# Django. Generate a lot of initial data (Factories ? )

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am interested in generate a lot of dumb data in Django using my models and I wonder if It could be possible to do this using something like Factories in Laravel.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have [model_mommy](https://github.com/vandersonmota/model_mommy) which is good